# Blender: can I render a scene to a very large output image by split cameras?

Tags: blender

In Blender, I am trying to render a huge scene in a very large image output (30000 x 18000).

This is for game background assets which will be sliced up into smaller POT images, and I am trying to preserve the details because the camera is zoomed in-game (hence the large image output).

I can technically just render this as is but it may cause some rendering performance issues.

So I am wondering if there is a way to split my camera into 4 smaller cameras, each one rendering a 15000x9000 image, a quadrant of the whole image, which I will then combine in PS, before slicing it up again.

Or is there a way to accurately position 4 cameras so that they are pixel-accurate rendering a quadrant of the whole image?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to setup multiple cameras or even move the camera. A small python script can chop up the render for you. One drawback to this is blender doesn't update it's window while rendering from a script.

As it sounds like you want to cut up the final image anyway you may want to cut it into the final pieces using this.

Don't expect to see any benefit as far as increased performance or reduced ram usage, as each render needs to load the entire scene data, think about reflections and shadows. There are still some benefits to doing it this way, you can have the final image files created at render time, you can stop and start rendering when doing only one image needs to be finished in one go, you can also share the load across muiltiple computers, letting each computer render a different set of tiles.

Blender has a feature called [Render Border](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/object/types/camera/introduction.html#render-border) that allows you to render only a portion of the final image. Using python you can set the border to the desired size and render multiple times. And the best part is you can also crop the final image to the specified border, but if you don't crop and you save to an image format that supports alpha, you will end up with a final resolution image that is transparent outside of the rendered area, which means you can open each image as a new layer and the pieces are automatically in the right position for the final image.

The border min/max values are a percentage of the final resolution, entered as a value between 0.0 and 1.0.

```
import bpy
import os

# cut final image into 10 by 10 smaller images
cut_into = 10
# location of folder to save images to
output_folder = '//renders'

rndr = bpy.context.scene.render

rndr.use_border = True
rndr.use_crop_to_border = False

for row in range(cut_into):
    for column in range(cut_into):
        filename = "chunk_{}_{}".format(row + 1, column + 1)
        rndr.filepath = os.path.join(output_folder, filename)

        rndr.border_min_x = (1 / cut_into) * row
        rndr.border_max_x = (1 / cut_into) * (row + 1)
        rndr.border_min_y = (1 / cut_into) * column
        rndr.border_max_y = (1 / cut_into) * (column + 1)

        bpy.ops.render.render( write_still=True )
```

If you haven't used python in blender before, you can paste this script into blender's [text editor](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/text_editor.html) and click the Run Script button. Or you can use it without a GUI by saving it to a text file and using a terminal -

```
blender -b myfile.blend -P this_script.py
```